# YQL query to get all symbols for a given year?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am attempting to get all ticker symbols from yahoo finance for a given year. I am assuming this can be accomplished using a YQL query. Can someone please advise on writing this query please. I would like something along the lines of the following:

```
select symbol from yahoo.finance.quote where date >= "01/01/2012" and date <= "31-12-2012"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a complete list of ticker symbols from Yahoo Finance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246843/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-ticker-symbols-from-yahoo-finance)

Comment: not a duplicate, the solution for the link you provided was in c# which i do not have and therefore will not be able to use

Comment: No reason you can't look at the code and figure out how to apply it to your chosen language.