# How do I use Quantmod to query Yahoo for the existence of a stock symbol

Tags: r, yahoo-api, quantmod

I've been using Quantmod in R and been using the

`getSymbols(allsymbols, src = 'yahoo', warnings = TRUE)`

However I've got a file of over 8000 stocks I want to query and a lot of them aren't valid in Yahoo's data source.

So I'd like to check them against the list of existing stocks and then adjust the list of Symbols to only include valid ones.

I've gone through Quantmod documentation and can't find anything there. Maybe it's not possible within Quantmod, but perhaps another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did an extensive amount of research a while ago on this and unfortunately didn't get anywhere. The only list you can get effortlessly is through `stockSymbols {TTR}` function which hands in a limited list of almost 7000 ticker symbols, traded on AMEX NASDAQ and NYSE, from Yahoo! Finance:

```
require(TTR)
tickersList <- stockSymbols()
```

FYI there's been a detailed discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246843/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-ticker-symbols-from-yahoo-finance).

Hope it helps.